# How to load variable in Angular with http get

Tags: angular, http

I have an angular service class that looks like this:

[image]

How do I use it to load a variable(USStates) in app.component.ts?

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me the issue in detail?

Comment: Please share any relevant code [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) by editing your Question. Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do as you already doing with `ChildToParentService`. First you inject the service `GetUSSStatesService` in your constructor and after you call subscribe on the observable `GetUSSStates()`

```
constructor(private ussStateService: GetUSSStatesService) {
    this.ussStateService
      .GetUSSStates()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((usStates: LUIItem[]) => {
        this.USStates = [...usStates];
      });
  }
```

Pipe(take(1)) is used to unsubscribe

Answer (score -1):

Observables emit when they are ready, and not before.

HttpClient.get() returns an observable that, once a value has been retrieved, emits *and caches it*. Then, if anything subscribes to it in the future, it will emit that same result instantly without pinging the server.

Therefore, instead of method that generates a new observable each time, you probably want to replace that method with a read-only property called something like `USStates$` that is set to whatever HttpClient.get() returns.

To use it, anything that needs it should inject the service directly instead of trying to go through AppComponent, and instead of subscribing to the observable, components' templates can use `getUSStatesService.USStates$ | async`, and service code can pipe it and provide their own observables.

*Ideally,* in Angular, you'll never need to subscribe to an observable, instead using the async pipe within the template as with this example. In this way, you never have to remember to unsubscribe because it's all handled for you.